# ExtJS: Where does the container default style come from?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

This is how I specify my "blank" container in JavaScript:

> Ext.create('Ext.container.Container');

The following screenshot shows the `style` attribute my container has by default (the `div` in question is selected):

[image]

As you can see it has:

```
style="left: 0px; top: 9px; margin: 0px;"
```

1. Where does this come from?
2. How can I "clean" it to have *no* style at all *by default*? I didn't specify `style` on the container so I can't figure out where this comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This settings comes from layout. If you want get rid of it you can specify `layout: auto` in container config.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rr2Vx/

Comment: Indeed specifying `layout:'auto'` removes that "default" style. Thanks.